# How to merge rows within a specific column?

Tags: tables, multirow

I need to create a table like this:

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\footnotesize}p{2.5cm}}
...
\begin{center}
\normalsize
\makebox[1 \textwidth][c]{
\resizebox{1.3 \textwidth}{!}{
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
    \begin{tabular}{|lll|N|}
    \hline
       Planck's function & $B_{\nu}(T)=\frac{2h\nu^{3}}{c^2}{\,}\frac{1}{e^{h\nu / kT}-1}$ & (1.1) & placeholder\\ \cline{1-3}
        d & c & b & a
    \end{tabular}}}}
\end{center}
```

which gives me this:

[image]

I would like to have the last column condensed like the first picture does. I tried using multirow but I couldn't figure out how to structure it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\displaystyle}X<{$}}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\footnotesize}p{3cm}}
\newlength\PlanckLength % ouch!
\settowidth{\PlanckLength}{Planck's}

\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
  \begin{tabular}{@{} % width of 2nd column is a residual
       >{$}wl{2.5mm}<{$} 
       >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5mm-2\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
  #1
  \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup}

\begin{document} 

\begin{center}
\normalsize % are you sure you need this?
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| >{\raggedright}m{\PlanckLength} L r | N|}
\hline
Planck's function & 
B_{\nu}(T)=\frac{2h\nu^{3}}{c^2}{\,}\frac{1}{\exp(h\nu / kT)-1} & 
(1.1) & 
\mytab{ \alpha   & right ascension of date \\
        \alpha_0 & right ascension at J2000.0 \\
        N        & number of years since J2000.0} \\
\cline{1-3}
a & b & c & d \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up questions: If what's needed is (a) automatic equation numbering and (b) a method for introducing line breaks in an equation if and when needed, I suggest you (i) switch from a four-column to a three-column layout for the `tabularx` environment and (ii) employ some of the display-math environments of the `amsmath` package, such as `align`, `gather`, and `multline`, as appropriate, to typeset both the (possibly multi-line) equation and the associated equation number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\footnotesize}p{3cm}}

\newlength\PlanckLength % ouch!
\settowidth{\PlanckLength}{Planck's}  % width of 1st column

\counterwithin{equation}{section} % just for this example

\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{1pt} % for a less cramped "look"
  \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt
  \begin{tabular}{@{} 
       >{$}wl{2.5mm}<{$} 
       >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5mm-2\tabcolsep\relax} 
       @{}}
    #1
  \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup}

\begin{document} 
\stepcounter{section} % just for this example

\begin{center}
\normalsize % are you sure you need this?
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| 
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\PlanckLength} 
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}X | 
    N |}
\hline
Planck's function & 
\begin{equation}
B_{\nu}(T)=\frac{2h\nu^{3}}{c^2} \, \frac{1}{\exp(h\nu/( kT))-1} 
\end{equation}
& 
\mytab{ \alpha   & right ascension of date \\
        \alpha_0 & right ascension at J2000.0 \\
        N        & number of years since J2000.0} \\
\cline{1-2}
a & b & c \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks very tidy. I still need to figure out some of the code, but overall feels more intuitive than multirow

Comment: Nice! For the sake of curiosity, is it possible to use automatic numbering of the equation?

Comment: Suppose I have a longer equation than Planck's function, I tried using \shortstack to start a new line but it messes up the vertical alignment. Is there a way around this?

Comment: \makecell works but it shrinks the font size for some reason

Comment: @HalcyonMo - Please see the addendum I posted a short while ago. Not sure what to say about how you use `\makecell`. Do you write `\makecell{$...$}` or `\makecell{$\displaystyle ... $}`?

Comment: adding `\displaystyle` to makecell solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt with `tabularray` (it's my very first use of this package…).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{equation}
    E_c=\frac{1}{2}MV^2
    \label{eq:Ec}
  \end{equation}
  
  \begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
        width=\textwidth,
        colspec={|t{6em}|X[1]l|lt{7em}|},
        column{2}={mode=dmath},
        column{4}={font=\footnotesize,mode=math,rightsep=1pt},
        column{5}={font=\footnotesize,leftsep=0pt}
      }
    \hline
    \SetCell[r=3]{m} Planck's function &  \SetCell[r=3]{m} B_{\nu}(T)=\frac{2h\nu^{3}}{c^2}{\,}\frac{1}{e^{h\nu / kT}-1} & \SetCell[r=3]{m} \eqref{eq:Planck} & \alpha   & right ascension of date \\
                                       &                                                                                 &                        & \alpha_0 & right ascension at J2000.0 \\
                                       &                                                                                 &                        & N        & number of years since J2000.01\\
    \cline{1-3}
    a                                  & b                                                                               &                        & c        & d\\
    \cline{1-3}
    \SetCell[r=2]{m} A very veeryy veeeryyy veeeeryyyy long name  & \SetCell[r=2]{m} P=mg                                & \SetCell[r=2]{m} \eqref{eq:Pmg} & m        & mass\\
                                       &                                                                                 &                               & g        & \qty{9.81}{\metre\per\second\squared}\\
    \hline
  \end{tblr}
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:Planck}
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:Pmg}
  \end{table}
  
  \Cref{eq:Ec} then \cref{eq:Planck} and last \cref{eq:Pmg}.
  \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this looks awesome too!